# Utilisation d'« aussi »

Tags: grammaire, adverbes, syntaxe

Est-ce que la position d'« aussi » change s'il est utilisé pour le sujet, le verbe ou l'objet ?

Par exemple :

> J'aime le cricket.

1. *Il aussi l'aime* (aussi s'applique à **il** qui est un autre sujet qui aime le cricket)
2. *Je le joue aussi* (aussi s'applique à **joue**, parce que c'est un autre action pour cricket qui je fais)
3. *J'aime le foot aussi* (aussi s'applique à **foot** qui est un autre sport que j'aime)

Answer (score 6):

Le sens d'une phrase peut changer suivant le fait qu'**aussi** s'applique à son sujet, à son verbe ou à son complément. Dans le premier cas, il faut aussi utiliser un pronom sujet tonique :

> *Il aime le cricket.*
> *Il aime aussi le cricket.*  (Il aime plusieurs choses dont le cricket).
> *Il aime le cricket aussi.* (Même sens).
> *Lui aussi aime le cricket.* (Des personnes aiment le cricket, il en fait partie).

À la première personne, on double le pronom:

> *Moi aussi, j'aime le cricket*. (*<s>Moi aussi aime</s> le cricket*)

> J'y joue aussi.  (Les deux sens sont possibles)
> Moi aussi, j'y joue.

> J'aime aussi le foot.
> J'aime le foot aussi. (Peut avoir les deux sens.)
> Moi aussi, j'aime le foot.

Le contexte peut aussi influer sur le sens à retenir. Les trois phrases suivantes ont sensiblement le même sens.

> Vous aussi (vous) êtes en vacances ?
> Vous êtes aussi en vacances ?
> Vous êtes en vacances aussi ?